# AWS equivalent to Azure Logic Apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-logic-apps, language-comparisons

Is there an AWS equivalent to Azure Logic Apps?

Furthermore I would like to know if someone has experiences regarding a migration of Azure Integration Services into AWS and if a comparison between Azure and AWS regarding the integration stack exists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the information provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services#miscellaneous), the equivalent of [`Logic Apps`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/logic-apps/) in AWS is [`Step Functions`](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/?step-functions.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&step-functions.sort-order=desc).

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to use [AWS Simple Workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-simple-workflow-cloud-based-workflow-management/).

I'm not sure about Azure Integration Services but it sounds like [AWS Migration Hub](https://aws.amazon.com/migration-hub/)